# BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset deprecated

Tags: flutter

`BitmapDescriptor` from `google_maps_flutter` is now used like:

```
BitmapDescriptor bitmap = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(configuration, assetName);
```

What should be used for `configuration`?

`BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage()` does not work as expected due to it returning a `Future<BitmapDesriptor>` rather than a `BitmapDescriptor`.